# why do I only get nulls in this IEnumerable<>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to populate this IEnumerable with values from a db.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
IEnumerable<Categories> categories = new List<Categories>();

List<SelectListItem> catItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach (var cats in categories)
{
    catItems.Add(new SelectListItem
                     {
                         Text = cats.CategoryName,
                         Value = cats.CategoryID.ToString()
                     });
}
```

Here is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SportsStore.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Categories
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: there should be something like `categories = GetCategoriesFromDB();`

Comment: I don't think you get nulls in your collection.. I think your collection is just empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only ever initialize a new collection of categories, there are never any added to the collection.

Comment: thanks, obvious stupid mistake. So, still getting use to MVC. in my ICategoriesReposity I call IQueryable<Categories> Categories { get; }.... this view only has "products", but I'm wanting to include the "categories" in this view, but couldn't find a way to return both. Any suggestions? thanks,

Comment: @ironman99 could you add to your question your code from `ICategoriesReposity`?

Answer (score 2):

How are you populating the categories list? It won't just get filled by saying...

```
IEnumerable<Categories> categories = new List<Categories>();
```

You need populate it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Because here you create a new (and empty) list of Categories:

```
IEnumerable<Categories> categories = new List<Categories>();
```

and here you try to iterate over the empty list:

```
foreach (var cats in categories)
{
```

Which means you're never adding anything to cat.Items